# Permissibility of Using Automatic Timer with Induction Heater for Vaporization on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Is it permissible according to Halacha to use an induction heater on Shabbat to heat up a metal object containing dry material, resulting in vaporization at a temperature of 200°C, as long as there is no combustion, fire, or flames, and the device is equipped with a preset automatic timer to turn on and off, similar to an electric stovetop on a mechanical timer?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Yes, as long as you *pasken* you can use a time switch.